# How to pass an ip address created by GCP to a compute instance metadata startup script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have created an internal load balancer for my microservice and iLB has internal IP where I want my external nginx to route the request based on a path. Now I need to pass the iLB ip address as upstream, I am trying to pass this iLB ip address as upstream when creating the nginx instance as a startupscript. I am just wondering anyone have passed any variable to the metadata script ?
Also to be clear, I am trying to achieve this through Terraform as I can easily get the iLB ip address as a pre-requisite before creating nginx cluster.
**nginx --> iLB --> uSvc's**

Answer (score 0):

Based on GCP doc, its possible to pass [metadata on startupscript](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#custom) but not directly possible to use "command like" arguments inside them, like by using `$1` and `$2`. However, it's possible for the startupscript to execute another script on a given path.

There is also some additional information regarding [custom metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#custom) that worth to mention.